# handling concurrency requests for tracks capacity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, concurrency, aws-lambda

Im developt software like warehouse managment.

And I have 1 problem.

Problem:

I have X tracks. Each track has his different capacity.

Now I have multi operators, which accept orders and fill the track.
When operator click on "Accept" - operator synchrony have to get response if orders accepted to selected track.
Let say Track A have capacity for 100 orders and currenlt has 98 orders inside.

Now 3 operators accept orders for this track ...

I want only 2 orders, and for the 3rd order show message, like - sorry, your order not accepted because here is noplace in the track..

Approach #1:
Just make lock on server.

Code:

Api Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TrackController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handle Request ");

            bool result = await TrackManager.ReservePlace();

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

TrackManager:

```
public static class TrackManager
    {
        private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphore { get; set; }
        public static void Init()
        {
            _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        }

        public static async Task<bool> ReservePlace()
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Order in process...");

           await  Task.Delay(2500); <<< ==== Just simulate the biggest delay with database

            _semaphore.Release();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Im really not like this approach.

The second approach - make something like deadlock in db.

Constrains in database not good option - because the track capacity is different.

---

Questions:

1) What is the best way to process concurrency requests and response syncrony?

2) Im thinking about transfer all this app to serverless (AWS Lambda) and their cloud db. What solution I can make their...because even my lock solution can be implement with Lambda....

Thank you.

Comment: Approach 1 is generally short sighted, since it restricts you to run on a single web server.

Comment: Have you read https://redis.io/topics/distlock ?

Comment: Note that you should wrap your code after `WaitAsync` in `try`/`finally` and release the semaphore in the finally.

Comment: @John Yeah - sure. Its just Pseudo code. But thank you

Comment: @mjwills No, I didnt check the redis....hmmm I will check now. Thank you.

Comment: You should check for [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). If you use Entity Framework there is built-in support. Which database are you using ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I want to use AWS database (probably DynamoDB)...or..Maybe ElasticCache - because here exist something like redlock in redis (Thank you @mjwills)